# Rails - Is there a way to autocomplete with form_tag attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb, form-fields

My search bar is using a form_tag type, and I can search and enter and it will show results, but it will not give autocompletion or suggestions when typing in the search bar.

When the user starts typing, I want it to display usernames.

Here is what I have tried:
This view is my application.html.erb and it is on my navbar. I dont know if that is also important.

```
    <%= form_tag users_path, :autocomplete => "on", :method => 'get', :id => 'users_search' do %>
        <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder:"search members..",style:"width:300px; height:35px;"
        %>
        <%= submit_tag "", :name => nil, :style => "display: none;" %>
    <% end %>
```

I also tried :autocomplete => :on in the text_field_tag. I'm just not sure how to go about this using form_tag.

Here is the rest of my code that may be important:

User_controller.rb

```
def index
    @users = User.search(params[:search])
end
```

User.rb

```
def self.search(username)
if username
    username.downcase!
    where("username LIKE ?","#{username}%")
else
    all
end
```

end

Comment: There are MANY ways. This is not a built in functionality that will just magically happen. You need to actually add an event handler and send an AJAX request to your backend and then update the document when you get the results. This is the topic for a great many existing tutorials and libraries and is off topic as its far to broad.

Comment: Also "The HTML autocomplete attribute lets web developers specify what if any permission the user agent has to provide automated assistance in filling out form field values, as well as guidance to the browser as to the type of information expected in the field" - it does not magically fetch data from your backend and should not be used for this purpose. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/autocomplete

Comment: Ah okay, I understand. Im quite unfamiliar with ajax but its definitely something I’ll look into. Thanks!